# RouterLinkActive does work in ngFor

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

*Will accept any javascript solution but best answer might be one using angular2*

I am trying to create my nav bar dynamically based on a api call.

The issue is I want the parent  li to have an active class if another li (child) is active.

**The below code works to what I want it to do but doesn't load it dynamically**

```
 <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a (click)="togglePatientSideSearch()"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-search"></i> <span class="menu-item-parent">Patient Search</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-nav-target="1" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: false }">
                        <a  (click)="toggleNavMenuParentSelected(1)" title="Dashboard"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-home"></i> <span class="menu-item-parent">Payroll</span>
                        <b class="collapse-sign">
                            <em class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></em>
                            </b>
                        </a>
                        <ul>
                            <li [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
                                <a [routerLink]="['/payroll/summary']" title="Payroll Summary"><span class="menu-item-parent">Summary</span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
                                <a [routerLink]="['/payroll/daily']" title="Payroll Daily"><span class="menu-item-parent">Daily</span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
</nav>
```

**The below code is what doesn't work that I am trying to fix!**

```
<nav>
            <ul *ngIf="navigationMenu">
                <li *ngFor="let nav of navigationMenu; let i = index;" [attr.data-nav-target]="nav.logo && !nav.children ? null : i" [attr.routerLinkActiveOptions]="nav.logo && !nav.children ? null : { exact: false }" [attr.routerLinkActive]="nav.logo && !nav.children ? null : ['active']" >
                    <a *ngIf="nav.logo && !nav.children" (click)="navigationClicked(nav)"><i class="{{nav.logo}}"></i> <span class="menu-item-parent">{{nav.name}}</span></a>
                    <a *ngIf="nav.logo && nav.children" (click)="toggleNavMenuParentSelected(i)" title="Dashboard">
                        <i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-home"></i> <span class="menu-item-parent">{{nav.name}}</span>
                        <b class="collapse-sign">
                            <em class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></em>
                        </b>
                    </a>
                    <ul *ngIf="nav.children">
                        <li [routerLinkActive]="['active']" *ngFor="let child of nav.children;">
                            <a [routerLink]="['/home']" title="Home"><span class="menu-item-parent">{{child.name}}</span></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

I am loading the whole nav bar at the same time in one object called navigationMenu. **Below is what I want it to look like vs what it is when dynamically loaded!** (ignore different names)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with this known bug: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14227

Comment: i guess this issue is fixed in new angular, update your packages to latest, also try to remove [] marks like `routerLinkActive="active"` and `routerLink="/user"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"
```

with your:

```
routerLinkActive="active"
```

I found the solution that worked for me here:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8397